# OpenVPN (Tunnelblick) Suddenly Dropping Constantly

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, openvpn

I've been using Tunnelblick on my Mac for OpenVPN for about a year now. All of a sudden, this morning, it decided that it was going to take a nasty turn for the worse with no explanation. Here are the symptoms I'm seeing:

- I can connect to the VPN fine, initially.
- After about 2 - 5 minutes of no interruption, the connection suddenly dies.
- I can still see the VPN route using `netstat -rn`, and Tunnelblick believes it's still connected.
- No VPN traffic can go through and I can't even ping the VPN gateway.
- Eventually, Tunnelblick will catch on that the connection has died (usually about 5 - 10 minutes later) and shoot itself to restart and then the cycle starts over again.

I've tried everything I can think of to figure this one out. I've completely flushed my system by rebooting and removing Tunnelblick and all traces of OpenVPN from my system and re-installing from scratch. No dice, same problem.

I'm at my wits end, because I desperately need to get this fixed as the VPN is required for me to be able to do my job. Any ideas you have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to this question to mark it resolved. Otherwise it'll get bumped to the front page again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrrrgghhh. I just realized that my machine at home is still connecting to the VPN and is auto-reconnecting every time it gets kicked off. I have two separate VPN keys for the two machines and apparently this machine somehow got the wrong key on it.

I put the right key on it and voila. No more problems.

Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Actually that was very helpful ;)